# compare math equations prior to evaluation javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm running through algebra and attempting to create a JavaScript tester function which compares two equations and determines if they are considered associative properties.  In other words, if I group (a + b) + c vs. a + (b + c) the result will be the same.  Multiplication and addition only.

Up to this point, I've attempted to build a simple function that resolves whether the final value is equal to the compared equation value.  What I would like is if I was able to compare both equations without their parenthesis.  Thinking I need to look up regular expressions... but looking for a little help on direction.

```js
let a = 1,
  b = 2,
  c = 3,
  number1 = (a * b) * c,
  number2 = a * (b * c);

function isAssociative(num1, num2) {
  let answer = num1 === num2;
  return `Are ${num1} and ${num2} associative... ${answer}`;
}

console.log(isAssociative(number1, number2));
```

Currently, this results in, 'Are 6 and 6 associative... true'.  This is what I want, but if I changed the second argument to a static 6 when calling the function... then this is not an associative combo and I would like it to return false.

Comment: I am not sure how that results in `Are 6 and 6 associative... true'`. That code should produce `Are (a * b) * c and a * (b * c) associative... false`

Comment: When the code *as written* runs, it returns `false` which is correct because the two "number" strings are not equal to each other.

Comment: I accidentally had them as a string while I was attempting some solutions.  I corrected it so they are numbers again and will equate to true.

Comment: Issue is if you do not have them defined as strings, you are not going to be able to know what it was originally to know if it was 6 or 2x6 or whatever. Issue with defined as strings is you need to somehow execute it. You have eval, new Function(), or parse it manually. Or you can look into libraries like math.js.

Comment: You are far away from a solution. What you are doing is comparing two numbers, if they are equal. What you need to do is lexically analyse two strings, simplify the analyzed objects and compare the two simplified objects. You will need a parser and tree objects for that. RegEx is not the right tool

Comment: You can use [Math.j](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) to do the [parsing](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html#parse)

Comment: @yunzen sorry about that.  Hit enter and then didn't edit in time.  Thanks for your help!  I was hoping to accomplish this on my own.  Is there a way to take a string equation, remove the parenthesis, and then return the strings to numbers and evaluate from there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer I'm satisfied with.

```
let number1 = prompt('Enter an equation').toString().replace(/[^0-9,+,*]+/g,''),
  number2 = prompt('Enter equation 2').toString().replace(/[^0-9,+,*]+/g,'');

function isAssociative (num1, num2) {
  if (num1 === num2) {
    return eval(num1) === eval(num2);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

alert(isAssociative(number1, number2));
```

I could wait for the numbers to enter the function as a string, check for parenthesis first to verify it even qualifies... if parenthesis exist, then I could execute the regEx code and if they don't exist return 'not associative' at that point.  For now, this works as well as I want it to.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Mathjs and the [simplify](http://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/simplify.html) method:

```js
console.clear();

term_a = 'a + ( b + c )'
term_b = '( a + b ) + c';

tree_a = math.simplify(term_a);
tree_b = math.simplify(term_b);

console.log(term_a, tree_a.equals(tree_b) ? 'equals' : 'differs from', term_b);

term_a = 'a + ( b + c + d )'
term_b = '( a + b ) + c';

tree_a = math.simplify(term_a);
tree_b = math.simplify(term_b);

console.log(term_a, tree_a.equals(tree_b) ? 'equals' : 'differs from', term_b);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/5.4.2/math.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like your solution, for sure!  However, I wanted to create my own solution without the use of other libraries / frameworks.  Thanks for the help.